# Load balancing SDSL + ADSL with Zyxel USG-100

Tags: load-balancing, gateway, qos, zyxel, stability

I have a Zyxel gateway/firewall, and two Internet connections : SDSL (4MB up, 4MB down) and ADSL (15MB down, 1MB up).

I'm trying to configure my Zyxel to use the two connections, and to use the SDSL in priority.

I added a rule on the trunk, here is my configuration :
[image: trunk spillover]

The thing is, my connection is very unstable. I have about 30 computers on my network, and if one of them download something, it monopolizes the bandwidth. The other get a catastrophic connection. See this ping on google.com for example :

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22681
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22682
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22683
64 bytes from 173.194.78.94: icmp_seq=22677 ttl=43 time=7200.496 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.78.94: icmp_seq=22678 ttl=43 time=7193.714 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22686
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22687
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22688
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22689
64 bytes from 173.194.78.94: icmp_seq=22686 ttl=43 time=4240.830 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.78.94: icmp_seq=22687 ttl=43 time=4165.275 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.78.94: icmp_seq=22688 ttl=43 time=4167.476 ms
```

The question is : how do I get a stable connection to Internet using the two connections and for all my computer at the same time ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong way. You have two different Internet connection, but not one connection with two trunked lines. I think you operator know notihg about trunk on your lines. Packet that leave first line has some source IP, but when leaves second line has other source IP. You configuration as you see have no chance to work.

I don't know your router, but configure this as two different lines. Or consult configuration with your internet provider.

When bonding is impossible, idea is router decide what external networks are serviced by first line, and what by second.

Maybe this will help you:
https://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bond-two-different-internet-connections

Comment: I think that the term trunk is confusing. The Zyxel definition of the trunk is to use multiple Internet connections and configure load balancing between them, it has nothing to do with the VLAN stuff. Fot the session issue, the router has the "Link Sticking" configuration to keep the sessions.